# Deleting a view from a ScrollView

Tags: javascript, scrollview, titanium-mobile

Developing in Titanium Mobile.

I need to remove a view from a scrollView when a delete button is clicked. I have a custom event firing when my button is clicked, which the scrollView listens for. My question is, how do I reference the view that needs to be deleted? These views are added to the scrollView dynamically, and there is no unique information about the view. I tried passing the view itself when firing the custom event, but this does not work. How do I tell the scrollView which view to delete?

Comment: it is possible to assign a unique identifier during creation and you can use that later

Comment: Like ID: myUniqueID ? I thought about this, but I need to come up with a way to create a uniqueID. I guess I could use a random number. The scrollView can actually contain duplicate items, so there is nothing about the view itself that is unique. Also, how do I find that view? Do I loop through all of the scrollView children checking against there IDs ?

Comment: which view you want to delete, if you have several and just one button?

Comment: There are several views within the scrollView. Each view has it's own delete button which resides within that view. When clicked, I want to remove that view from the scrollView, as well as delete an object which I have stored as a global var.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a delete button inside the view - that's a piece of cake :) Just get its' parent and delete it - `scrollView.remove(e.source.parent);`

Here I created a demo page:

```
var scrollView = Titanium.UI.createScrollView({ 
    contentWidth: 'auto', 
    contentHeight: 'auto', 
    top: 0, 
    showVerticalScrollIndicator: true, 
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator: true,
    layout: 'vertical'
}); 

var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'purple', 'yellow'];

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

    var view = Ti.UI.createView({ 
        backgroundColor: colors[i], 
        borderRadius: 10, 
        width: 300, 
        height: 200, 
        top: 10,
        id: i
    });
    scrollView.add(view); 

    var deleteButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
        borderRadius: 3,
        style: Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.PLAIN,
        backgroundGradient: {
            type: 'linear', 
            colors: [ '#c7c7c7', '#686868' ], 
            startPoint: { x: 0, y: 0 }, 
            endPoint: { x: 0, y: 30 }, 
            backFillStart: false
        },
        title: 'Delete view ' + i,
        font: { fontSize: 12, fontWeight: 'bold' },
        color: '#fff',
        width: 120,
        height: 30
    });
    view.add(deleteButton);

    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        Ti.API.info(e.source.id); // use this ID
        scrollView.remove(e.source.parent);
    });

}

Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(scrollView);
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the views (e.src.parent) index within the scrollView? Reason I ask is because I would like to also delete an object that is associated with this view. This object is stored in globally in a list. I figure the index of the view is going to be the same as the index of the object within the list.

Comment: That would be hard to get the index since it's not a TableView. The easiest way probably is to set an ID to the view (I've updated the code above), give the same ID to your object upon creation and when deleting - delete the object with the requested ID.